# verbose logging - How to enable logging for web services calls

Tags: logging

What to enable in the Monitoring in order to capture the logs for the web services calls? We are using Kofax to load documents. It works for all the site collection except one site collection. I looked at the SP log and did not see any entry even for successful loads. No logs for sitecollection (working site coll or the one that's not working), no logs for the service account that kofax is using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for Verbose logging to work for Web Service calls in SharePoint, those calls need to write to the ULS log.  In some cases, third-party web services are not coded to write to the ULS logs.  I would check the Event Viewer to see if they are writing to that.

In addition, you could look at the IIS logs or check with the developer of the web services to see how you can get the logging you are looking for with their web services.

Comment: I looked at the IIS Log and I didn't see traffic from the Server who is processing the upload or the host ip. Kofax have logging but it's generic.

Comment: In the IIS logging, you can configure additional fields to be logged.  See if those have what you are looking for.